# Unable to select the login popup window in Python using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log in on this page using Python and Selenium, but that popup login window is driving me crazy. After I open it, it seems like Python does not recognize it because I can't click on anything in that window. I printed to see if it is a window handle, alert window, or iframe, but it is none of those. What could it be? How can I click on that window?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#

# Set up the webdriver
#driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

# Open the website
driver.get("https://www.test.dk/")


# Wait for the accept banner to be clickable and click it
accept_banner = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "coi-banner__accept"))
)
accept_banner.click()

# Wait for the "Log ind" button to be clickable and click it
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Log ind']"))
)
login_button.click()


# Wait for the "Log ind med email" button to be clickable
email_login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Log ind med email")]')))

# Click on the "Log ind med email" button
email_login_button.click()


driver.quit()
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is not in the popup window; rather, the issue lies in the fact that there are two forms on the page, both containing fields for username, password, and a submit button. I don't know why.

```
# Find all elements with the text "Log ind med email"
email_login_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Log ind med email")]')))
# Choose the second "Log ind med email" button
email_login_button = email_login_buttons[1]
# Now, you can interact with the button as needed
email_login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you notice the above HTML, `Log ind med email` is within `<span>` node, and not `<button>` node.

So, change your XPath expression as below:

```
//span[contains(text(), "Log ind med email")]
```

Having said that, above XPATH expression is finding 2 web elements in the HTML. You need the first one. So, the XPATH expression should be:

```
(//span[contains(text(), "Log ind med email")])[1]
```

Also, instead of `presence_of_element_located`, use `element_to_be_clickable`. See full code below.

```
email_login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//span[contains(text(), "Log ind med email")])[1]')))
```